# JRebel and Dynamic Class Loading

Tags: java, jrebel

I have a few questions regarding JRebel and Java's Dynamic Class Laoding.

Say for example, In a servlet I can reload servlet classes in the classes directory of the WEB-INF directory such that any time I change the class's contents and after complation I can see the changes reflected straight in my web-app without re-building my web appliaction.

What does JRebel offer beyond what's mentioned above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides Java class reloading JRebel provides the integration for the wide range of technologies in the Java ecosystem. By that I mean integration with all kind of containers and frameworks.

The integration with containers is needed in order to be able to work in the Java EE world. For instance if you want to add a new EJB on the fly. To support framework-specific changes there are special plugins incorporated with JRebel. For instance if you want to add a new bean in Spring context and get it injected somewhere else.. or add new Struts actions on the fly... or see the changes to your Java classes in JSP scriplet. There's a lot of [features](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/features/) to list

The full list of the specific framework integrations is available on the [website](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/features/frameworks/)

Comment: Is Jrebel reloading apllicable to classes out side the classes directory.The JEE envirnment does not allow the classes outside the classes directory to be re-loaded.Does Jrebel allow this?

Comment: JRebel will reload classes that it sees. You can map the classes in the way you would like, with rebel.xml configuration file. They can be either in dependencies or in shared libs, etc.

Comment: Basically, it is possible to deploy an empty war file, for instance, with rebel.xml and web.xml only and then load all the resource from where you have them