# Pause and execute JSP file

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Is there a way to pause a jsp file after calling a Servlet and execute the remaining code after the servlet execution is completed?

Comment: by new servlet do u mean a new entry in web.xml ?

Comment: not possible! you need to restart

Comment: You can consider using JRebel. See more info here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582377/jrebel-and-dynamic-class-loading][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582377/jrebel-and-dynamic-class-loading

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884310/dynamically-add-a-servlet-to-the-servletconfig is an option. Also, JRebel is free for non-commercial use only.

Comment: I'm failing to see what JRebel has to do with the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dynamic include should do exactly that. Something along the lines of the following:

```
<jsp:include page="/path/to/your/servlet" />
```